# How can i change the fill color of an SVG image using nativescript

Tags: css, angular, svg, nativescript

I am using Angular Nativescript to build an Android application. I want the app to show some SVG images and change their color dpending on which page they are in. I tried to change the 'fill' in the CSS but nothing happened. How can i change it?